# Running a process messes up shell

Tags: shell, go, command-line, stdin, osquery

I need to run a process called `osqueryi` before I run my app, and when shutting down, killing that process. (It is kind of a daemon which can be queried. I need it to be running in order for my app to work).

```
func bootOsqueryi(strcmd string) {
  cwd, err := os.Getwd()
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  pa := os.ProcAttr{
    Files: []*os.File{os.Stdin, os.Stdout, os.Stderr},
    Dir:   cwd,
  }
  path, err := exec.LookPath(strcmd)
  if err != nil {
    handleError(err)
    return
  }
  osqueryi, err := os.StartProcess(path, []string{strcmd}, &pa)
  if err != nil {
    handleError(err)
    return
  }
  osqueryi.Wait()
}
```

I call this from a cobra `PersistentPreRun` hook like this: `go bootOsqueryi("osqueryi")`.

In the `PersistentPostRun` hook I shut it just down:

```
func shutdown() {
  if osqueryi != nil {
    osqueryi.Kill()
  }
}
```

`Osqueryi` is like an interactive shell. It needs to be passed `os.Stdin`, because apparently it uses `isatty`. If I don't do that, it doesn't run. So I need to start this process because I need to query it but I don't need to write any input to it because the idea is to use a go module `osquery-go` to issue queries from my app...

I need to call it in a `go` routine because otherwise I can't write log output to the screen...

In any case, it kinda works well. BUT, when the app terminates, my terminal is messed up: my prompt line is missing (can't see what I type). I guess, because I am assigning it STDIN but I am never writing to it and in the meanwhile writing output to STDOUT via `fmt.Println()`.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: `stty sane` fixes it but I am not sure how interoperable this is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged osquery, so... Perhaps as an alternative, don't run `osqueryi` that way, it's not meant to be used like that.

The general recommendation is to use `osqueryd` with the configuration as you'd like it. Or, if you really want to a single invocation of `osqueryi` you can invoke it with a query from the command line, outputting in json:

```
osqueryi --json "select 1"
[
  {"1":"1"}
]
```

`osqueryi` is not really the same as `osqueryd`.

Comment: With the very generous and friendly help of folks over at the `osquery` slack channel, I was able to transition from using `osqueryi` to start `osqueryd` with custom parameters, which is the intended way, as this answer suggests. My terminal nightmare is gone at least.

Comment: If someone gets here for different reasons, using a `pseudo` terminal with the https://github.com/creack/pty package does help to fix the messed up terminal, as I was able to assign the pseudo-terminal to the process and things were kinda working as well, as STDIN was not being shared and messed up by the processes. However, I have no idea how cross-platform such a solution could be and how well it would work in real production settings.